# Is this an annual?

Tags: identification, flowering

What kind of flower is this? I had many die but not sure if it a perrianial or an annual.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commonly known as Pansy, its Viola tricolor. They sometimes carry on for a couple of years, but they don't usually do so, and even if they do, the flowering is significantly reduced. They sometimes seed themselves, but otherwise are treated as an annual.